# CSS list border bottom spacing issue

Tags: php, html, css, navbar

I am having issues with this bit of CSS and I can't seem to find it out.

I have a bit of PHP:

```
<ul>
<?php if($page=="home"){echo"<li class='active'>";}else{echo"<li>";}?><a href="http://www.trevorpeyton.com/" alt="Home page">Home</a></li> 
<?php if($page=="about"){echo"<li class='active'>";}else{echo"<li>";}?><li><a href="http://www.trevorpeyton.com/about/" alt="Learn all about me">About</a></li> 
<?php if($page=="contact"){echo"<li class='active'>";}else{echo"<li>";}?><li><a href="http://www.trevorpeyton.com/contact/" alt="Contact me">Contact</a></li> 
<?php if($page=="projects"){echo"<li class='active'>";}else{echo"<li>";}?><li><a href="http://www.trevorpeyton.com/projects/"alt="View projects I am working on/completed">Projects</a></li> 
<?php if($page=="sites"){echo"<li class='active'>";}else{echo"<li>";}?><li><a href="http://www.trevorpeyton.com/sites/" alt="View websites I have made">Sites</a></li> 
<?php if($page=="demo"){echo"<li class='active'>";}else{echo"<li>";}?><li><a href="http://www.trevorpeyton.com/demo/" alt="Demo the new user features">Demo</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Now, on each page it will define `$page`. The issue is when a page is active it displays a bar underneath the item. The bar is floating to the right side of the page and the home item is on the far right. If that one is active then it works just fine. When any of the other items are active then the line is to the left. Here is my CSS:

```
#header {
position:fixed;
background:#222;
color:#999;
width:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
top:0;
z-index:1;
height:5%;
}
#header ul li{
display: inline;
margin:0;
float:right;
display:block;
padding:5px 10px;
}
#header .active{
border-bottom: solid 3px orange;
}
```

Right

[image: Right]

Wrong

[image: Wrong]

I know it has something to do with the spacing but I just can't figure it out. I'm not a CSS guy.

Comment: Why would you post PHP code when asking a 'CSS/HTML' question?

Comment: @Connor Because people snap at you when you don't show ALL the code. The PHP part is essential but not causing the problem.

Comment: It's not essential please can you copy the output HTML

Comment: Even better - reproduce the problem on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar

Comment: 1) Your php code is missing the </ul>. 2) the bar underneath you're talking about is the border-bottom? 3) Are you sure you want to float them to the right?

Comment: @aldux It was in there I just forgot to add the four spaces (I edited it). Yes, the border-bottom tag. Ya, I have other things on the left side of the page nav bar. I know it's not something you see every day, that's the point though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that you are outputting more than the needed `<li>` tags

```
<?php if($page=="demo"){echo"<li class='active'>";}else{echo"<li>";}?><li><a href="http://www.trevorpeyton.com/demo/" alt="Demo the new user features">Demo</a></li>
```

this will either output

```
<li class='active'>
   <li><a href="http://www.trevorpeyton.com/demo/" alt="Demo the new user features">Demo</a></li>
```

or

```
<li>
   <li><a href="http://www.trevorpeyton.com/demo/" alt="Demo the new user features">Demo</a></li>
```

So to see if this is the problem use this

```
<ul>
    <?php if($page=="home"){echo"<li class='active'>";}else{echo"<li>";}?><a href="http://www.trevorpeyton.com/" alt="Home page">Home</a></li> 
    <?php if($page=="about"){echo"<li class='active'>";}else{echo"<li>";}?><a href="http://www.trevorpeyton.com/about/" alt="Learn all about me">About</a></li> 
    <?php if($page=="contact"){echo"<li class='active'>";}else{echo"<li>";}?><a href="http://www.trevorpeyton.com/contact/" alt="Contact me">Contact</a></li> 
    <?php if($page=="projects"){echo"<li class='active'>";}else{echo"<li>";}?><a href="http://www.trevorpeyton.com/projects/"alt="View projects I am working on/completed">Projects</a></li> 
    <?php if($page=="sites"){echo"<li class='active'>";}else{echo"<li>";}?><a href="http://www.trevorpeyton.com/sites/" alt="View websites I have made">Sites</a></li> 
    <?php if($page=="demo"){echo"<li class='active'>";}else{echo"<li>";}?><a href="http://www.trevorpeyton.com/demo/" alt="Demo the new user features">Demo</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Good catch -- and ironically contradicts @Connor's comment about posting PHP :) (although to counter that: the OP hopefully would have noticed the double `<li>` and maybe wouldn't have even asked the question at all)

Comment: Ya, I should have been more cautious. Simple mistake, thanks.

Comment: So, was that the issue?

Comment: @Connor Yes, you answered it so fast though that I can't accept it just yet.

Comment: Ok. Cool....... @gregmac you have half a point. you would have a whole point if the question was about PHP, us assuming it's a CSS Error so we can't make a fiddle out of PHP **:D**

Comment: @Connor Ya, really the error was just me missing some essentials but I guess I'll add a PHP tag in there because I did have PHP. I thought it was something to do with the CSS spacing in between each item.